# Apache Storm: How does WindowedBoltExecutor handle FailedException?

Tags: apache-storm

After a tuple falls out of the window, the WindowedBoltExecutor does a
`windowedOutputCollector.ack(tuple);`. However, I could not find what happens when `boltExecute` method throws a `FailedException`.

`BasicBoltExecutor` handles this explicitly like [this](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/e7731a547ae113d2fbc0fda6a9f02fc3d78de5fb/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/topology/BasicBoltExecutor.java#L50). I could not find the equivalent handling for `WindowedBoltExecutor`. How are the failed tuples handled? Thanks in advance.